# ехать или ездить, идти или ходить

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, глаголы

Sometimes I know which verb to use but sometimes it is hard for me to decide.

1. Is it rule that with verb **ЛЮБИТЬ** we should always use **ХОДИТЬ**, **ЕЗДИТЬ**, ... instead of **ИДТИ**, **ЕХАТЬ**, ...?
2. Уже восемь? Я **ЕДУ** на работу! (Is it possible to use here **ИДУ** if we are going by foot - ПЕШКОМ?)
3. Мы **ЕДЕМ** на море, а они **ЕДУТ** отдыхать в деревню. (Is this correct?)

Comment: You can remember the correct form of поезжай, using this simple poem:
Косолапенький медведь,
ты не ехай и не едь,
и не ездий никогда!
Поезжай, запомнил?
Да!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "Люблю ездить/ходить" is correct in most cases, but:

a) If you like the process of walking/riding/driving and doing something else in the same time, you can also say, for example: "люблю идти по ночному городу и наслаждаться тишиной". This form is somewhat poetical, but is also OK in informal speech.

b) There are collocations like "идти на риск" or "идти в [размен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B))" in which "ходить" is never used.

#2 and #3 are answered well by others.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. **Люблю ходить пешком**, **люблю ездить летом на море**, etc.
2. Actually **идти на работу** is idiomatically correct regardless of means of transportation. (Unless you specify the means.)
3. Yes, if both are referring to a single trip. If you're asking about the ending, it's been fixed by Eugene in the edit. **Едят** is a form of **есть**, not **ехать**.

(Sorry for the duplicate answer, I was meaning to edit.)

Answer (score 1):

1. verb ЛЮБИТЬ is both for "love" and "like" 
   Люблю идти/ехать - rare used it is like continuous action. 
   Люблю ходить/ездить - much more correct - this about an action that you like to do - for example you have two abilities to reach your work place - by car or by foot.
   And you tell someone that "Люблю ходить to my work place" - this will be ".. I choosing "by foot" rather then use any other ability to reach this place"
2. Correct
3. Correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what the question is about.
2. Correct.
3. они ЕДУТ отдыхать. они ЕДЯТ арбуз (they are eating watermelon).

Answer (score 0):

The **simpliest** explanation:

*I*. **идти**/**ехать** is a process. Literally - *be going (by foot/by car)*. Я **иду** на работу - *I'm going* to work (*now*). Compare: Я **хожу** на работу - I *go* to work (*every workday*). And yes, we use **ехать/ездить** only if it's *by car/bus/underground*, etc., if the *whole* way is *by foot*, we use **идти/ходить**.

*II*. If we use infinitive we can say **идти/ехать** if we mean a *single (non-repeated) action*. Я не хочу туда **идти**. - *I don't wanna go there (single action)*. Compare: Я не хочу **ходить** на работу. - *I don't wanna go to work (not just today, but in general - meaning repeated action)*.

*III*. In '*when*' clauses we use **идти/ехать**, because we mean the process itself again. Когда я **иду** на работу, я не отвечаю на звонки. - *When I'm going to work I don't answer phone calls*. (not sure continuous form is appropriate here in English, sorry if I'm mistaken). "Когда я хожу..." would sound a bit unnatural. But in the past tense things differ. We use **ходил/ездил** in case we don't mean a single action, but *all those actions together*. Когда я **ездил** на работу, я никогда не видел этот дом. - *When I went to work I never saw that house* (I went to work lots of times of course). The opposite, we use "**шел/ехал**" if we mean *a single action*. Когда я вчера **шел** на работу, мне перебежала дорогу черная кошка. - *When I was going to work yesterday a black cat crossed my way*.

And yes, with **любить** we usually use "**ходить/ездить**" because we mean those actions in general but not a process. In the accepted answer there is "я люблю идти по ночному городу..." but for me it sounds unnatural (I'm a native). I'd say "я люблю ходить по ночному городу и наслаждаться тишиной". And yes with some idiomatic expressions like "идти на рожон" we use only this form.

Your #2 item: correct, because you don't mean here a repeated action in general.

Your #3 item: Мы **ЕДЕМ** на море - only *if we are doing it now*. *Otherwise* Мы **ЕЗДИМ**. The same is for the second part of your sentence.